# Upload PNG image using google ads api in ad group

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-ads-api

I am looking to enhance the visibility of an image on Google Ads through my Python project. After successfully creating a campaign, I attempted to push the png image using the Google Ads API. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any documentation specifically addressing this process. I do have the campaign ID, ad group ID, and asset ID, and I tried the following code. However, it only uploaded the image to assets and not into the Google Ads platform.[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myfsy.png)

I run this code it only add image in asset but it is not adding in ad group. It give me following error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.